# Problema con servidor tomcat8, crea muchísimos procesos

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, servidor

Tengo un servidor Tomcat8 donde tengo una aplicación web. La aplicación se lanzó hace un par de meses y ningún problema, pero desde hace una semana el servidor se bloquea porque usa toda la RAM de la máquina y no puede funcionar. La máquina es Debian y he hecho las siguientes pruebas:

Resultado comando `top`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado comando `ps -ef | grep tomcat`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado comando `ps aux | grep [t]omcat`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es como se crease muchos procesos hasta que acaba con la memoria. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor publica el resultado de `ps aux | grep [t]omcat`

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de subir el resultado de ese comando, lo que ocurre que acabo de reiniciar la máquina y ahora mismo no tiene el problema, por lo que no se si el resultado te vale.

Comment: Pues suena a que tienes algún proceso lanzando hilos y no los estás cerrando en tu aplicación. sshd2 es un secure shell daemon... a menos que lo estés instanciando explícitamente en tu aplicación, dudo que tenga que ver.

Comment: @Alfabravo he borrado completamente Tomcat y Java y los he vuelto a instalar y ahora no da ningún problema. Supongo que en algún momento alguno se habrá corrompido o algo. Muchas gracias.